# Select row with largest timestamp in each category

Tags: mysql, database, group-by

I have a MySQL database (blogs) that has a id, title, timestamp, and category_id column names. How can I select one row from each category that has the newest timestamp?
If I have 3 rows being in category 1, 2, 1, then I will get two rows back with the highest timestamp of the categories in "1" as the first and the row with category "2" as the second.

I tried:

```
SELECT title, timestamp, category_id
FROM blogs 
WHERE timestamp IN (
  SELECT MAX(timestamp) 
  FROM blogs 
  GROUP BY category_id
)
```

BUT since timestamp is not unique, it could, say, pull in an extra row with category_id = 1 that has the same timestamp as the row with category_id = 2 that was selected in the inner select statement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<strike>For MySQL, this query will return the result set you specified:</strike>

```
SELECT b.title
     , MAX(b.timestamp)
     , b.category_id
  FROM blogs b
 GROUP BY b.category_id
```

If there happen to be more than one "title" in a category that has the same latest "timestamp", only one row for that category will be returned, so you will get just one "title" returned for each category.

---

Note: other DBMS system will throw an exception (error) with a query like the one above, because of the handling of non-aggregates in the SELECT list that don't appear in the GROUP BY.

Your  query was very close.  You've already got that inner query returning the "latest" timestamp for each category. The next step is to return the category_id along with that latest timestamp.

```
SELECT category_id, MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp
  FROM blogs
 GROUP BY category_id
```

The next step is to join that back to `blogs`, to get the associated "title"(s)

```
SELECT b.title
     , b.timestamp
     , b.category_id
  FROM (SELECT category_id, MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp
          FROM blogs 
         GROUP BY category_id
       ) l
  JOIN blogs b
    ON b.category_id = l.category_id AND b.timestamp = l.timestamp
```

NOTE: if there is more than one "latest" row for a category (the timestamp values match), this query will return both of them.

If that's a concern, the query can be modified (or written in a different way) to prevent any possibility of two rows for a category.

---

Simply adding a GROUP BY clause to that query will work (in MySQL only, not other DBMSs)

```
SELECT b.title
     , b.timestamp
     , b.category_id
  FROM (SELECT category_id, MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp
          FROM blogs 
         GROUP BY category_id
       ) l
  JOIN blogs b
    ON b.category_id = l.category_id AND b.timestamp = l.timestamp
 GROUP BY b.timestamp, b.category_id
```

(For other DBMSs, you could modify the SELECT list, replace `b.title` with `MAX(b.title) AS title`. That will work when you are returning a single column from the row.

If you want the rows returned in a particular order, add an ORDER BY clause.

---

Comment: I'm getting an error on the first one, your description of it sounds great and what i want, but the SQL is erroring out. Is the "join" suppose to be "from"?

Comment: @Adam: yes it's supposed to be FROM. (My bad, I will get it fixed.) The queries after that are designed to work with multiple databases, that first one is MySQL specific, due to its handling of non-aggregates in the SELECT list that do not appear in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: when looking at the first query, it seems like it should work. But MAX() brings in the max timestamp value BUT the rows are still returned in basic order. EX:
If you have 6 rows with last 3 being the 3 highest, the first query will return the last three rows max timestamp value with the FIRST THREE ROWS id, title, etc. since they are id values 1,2,3 and being return first assuming 1&4 have same cat_id 2&5 do and 3&6 do

Comment: The other query definitely works though! Thanks a lot! Is there a way to return only one row per group? Like what if two diff rows have same timestamp and cat_id (also being the newest)?

Comment: @Adam: You are correct, that first query doesn't really return the specified result set, it just gets "some" title in the category, not necessarily the title associated with MAX(timestamp). Yes, I can improve that second query to guarantee only one row per category.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This has had me stumped for a fat minute

Comment: Thank you again. Worked great!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way too. Works for me when I tried in MYSQL 5.6. It returns two categories with the highest timestamp and ascending order of the category_id.

> SELECT title
>        , timestamp
>        , category_id   FROM blogs  WHERE timestamp in (select max(timestamp) from blogs group by category_id) group by
>   timestamp,category_id order by category_id asc;